# Chrome history issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, title

I am developing web application and for business need's I have to change `document.title` dynamically.

When I'm doing it in Firefox all changes updates link name in history, but if you will open history in Chrome (cmd+Y) you will see only initial page `<title/>`.

Comment: This is not a JavaScript issue, but just the way Chrome stores it's history.

Comment: Of course, it is Chrome way to store history. But I need workaround to add last title to history. pushState or something like that.